# I'm trying to switch between two angular components inside the app component with 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I'm working on an app where the design calls for 2 buttons and each of the buttons will show a different nested app. I can't use angular routing for this.

The 2 buttons are going to be placed inside the app.component.

Clicking **Button A** will display the **Nested Component A**,

Clicking **Button B** will display the **Nested Component B**

I thinks there's a way to do this with ngSwtich and ngSwitchcase, but I can quite get it right.

```
export class AppComponent { 

    types: SelectItem[];

    selectedType: string


    constructor() {
        this.types = [
            {label: 'Button A', value: 'A'},
            {label: 'Button B', value: 'B'}
        ];
}

}
```

here's the html

```
<h3 class="first">Choose View</h3>
<p-selectButton [options]="types" [(ngModel)]="selectedType"></p-selectButton>

<p>Selected Type: <span style="font-weight: bold">{{selectedType}}</span></p>







<!-- Switching Mechanism -->

<div [ngSwitch]="'selectedType'">
  <li *ngSwitchCase="A"> <app-component-a></app-component-a>
  <li *ngSwitchCase="B">  <app-component-b></app-component-b>
  <li *ngSwitchDefault><app-component-b></app-component-b>
</div>
```

I have been playing around in Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-6simfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw a Few Errors in the following section

**it should be "'A'" and "'B'"**

**it should be [ngSwitch]="selectedType"**

**Closing  braces for '</li>' were mising**

```
<div [ngSwitch]="selectedType">
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'A'"> <app-component-a></app-component-a></li>
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'B'">  <app-component-b></app-component-b></li>
</div>
```

**Correct the values of selected types**

```
constructor() {
    this.types = [
        {label: 'Button A', value: 'A'},
        {label: 'Button B', value: 'B'}
    ];
}
```

**Example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-xgtbaw

Answer (score 1):

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 

    types: SelectItem[];
    selectedType: string = 'Button A';


    constructor() {
        this.types = [
            {label: 'Button A', value: 'Button A'},
            {label: 'Button B', value: 'Button B'}
        ];
}

}
```

**component.html**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 

    types: SelectItem[];
    selectedType: string = 'Button A';


    constructor() {
        this.types = [
            {label: 'Button A', value: 'Button A'},
            {label: 'Button B', value: 'Button B'}
        ];
}

}
```

Comment: here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/santosh-primeng-selectbutton-demo

Comment: Thank you! I see what I was messing up on!